# Using Hibernate to insert into the database

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate

I have written this code to insert into a column in a table but it does not, I don't know what exactly is wrong with the code.

"WEB-INF.views.Register.cyclosUsersCreditLimit.value" is the path to an input control (textbox) on a jsp page. I think maybe possibly this is where I missed it. What needs to be done?

This is the DAO class:

```
@Override
        public void saveCyclosUsers(CyclosUsers cyclosUsers) {
            Object inputLowerCredit = null;
            inputLowerCredit = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().createSQLQuery("UPDATE Cyclos30.accounts SET credit_limit =" +"WEB-INF.views.Register.cyclosUsersCreditLimit.value" +" " 
                                                                                  +"WHERE owner_name =" +"WEB-INF.views.Register.ownerName.selectedItem");
            if(inputLowerCredit != null)
            {
                try
                {
                    sessionFactory.getCurrentSession().saveOrUpdate(inputLowerCredit);
                }
                catch(Exception exception)
                {
                    exception.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: first of all invoking fields from JSPs like that is not exactly best practice, can't you pass the form via a Controller to the service and then further on to the DAO? might be easier to debug

Comment: can you give us the error stack for this application? or is there any log displayed?

Comment: You are creating a `Query` object and try to pass that to the `saveOrUpdate` method, that obviously is never going to work. Seems to me you lacking basic understanding what hibernate is and does? What you want to do is to bind your input to the object you want to update, then store that object. Hibernate takes care of updating the fields.

Comment: it does not give any error. It simply does not update. From what @Bogdan Emil Mariesan, appreciate your comment. Could you give me a simple code or a tutorial that does that? I am a newbie. please your valid contributions would be highly appreciated by either providing the simple code that corrects my error or a tutorial that achieves what i want to do. Thanks.

Comment: try http://viralpatel.net/blogs/spring3-mvc-hibernate-maven-tutorial-eclipse-example/

Comment: Thanks. I have gone through this tutorial and it does not seem to answer exactly how to handle a "where clause statement", it is only saving a session object of the class in the db. Any tutorial that handles this?